# Override delete icon margin styles in MUI Chip component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using V4 MUI Chip component with `size : 'small'` and `variant: 'outlined'` with a `deleteIcon` specified.

https://v4.mui.com/components/chips/

I'd like to override the `margin-right` property of the `deleteIcon` but I'm having trouble getting the right specificity, because MUI is applying more specific styles.

The following styles are applied to the delete icon by MUI:

```
.MuiChip-outlined-253 .MuiChip-deleteIconSmall-267 {
    margin-right: 3px;
}
.MuiChip-outlined-253 .MuiChip-deleteIcon-266 {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

How do I apply a style to override the margin-right of the `deleteIcon` and set it to e.g. '10px'?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the class `.MuiChip-deleteIcon` based on the `Chip` api documentation (https://v4.mui.com/api/chip/)

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-bhuygs?file=/demo.js) to play with (has for the both default and outlined variants).

Here is the code to implement the change you want.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import FaceIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Face";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(0.5)
    },
    //Here is where you customise the css for the delete icon
    "& .MuiChip-deleteIcon": {
      marginRight: "20px", // Change those values to yours
    },
    //For customising the outlined the css for the delete icon 
    "& .MuiChip-outlined": {
      "& .MuiChip-deleteIcon": {
        marginRight: "10px", // Change those values to yours
      }
    }
  }
}));

export default function Chips() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleDelete = () => {
    console.info("You clicked the delete icon.");
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.info("You clicked the Chip.");
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Chip label="Deletable primary" onDelete={handleDelete} color="primary" />
      <Chip
        icon={<FaceIcon />}
        label="Deletable secondary"
        onDelete={handleDelete}
        color="secondary"
      />
      <Chip
        icon={<FaceIcon />}
        label="Deletable secondary"
        onDelete={handleDelete}
        color="secondary"
        variant="outlined"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Another way would be to do something similar in the theme.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the sandbox! I can see how you have added the class override. Unfortunately, applying a similar override to my own component still doesn't resolve - the style isn't applied and is overriden by the ones shown in my post.

I've tried troubleshooting (checking my theme - checking other styles) but no luck...and i can't replicate what i see in my code, in a sandbox which is frustrating! I may have to spend a bit more time checking what's going on with my code.

Comment: Can you share your code to check it? If the answer is correct please consider upvoting or mark as correct for future people with same question. Thanks

Comment: Yes! My code in the app is https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-chip-f3rbi9

Inspecting the styles (selecting the SVG deleteicon element) in my app shows that we don't override the `margin-right` or `margin-left`:
https://imgur.com/a/MHr64ib

But inspecting the same element in the codesandbox shows that we do:
https://imgur.com/a/CxwbadI

I've checked my theme (there are no style overrides for e.g. MUI-Chip). I even tried making a styled component itself and injecting the styles in the sandobx above. Still have no more clue about whats going on - happy to hear any suggestions? :)

Comment: Hi @MichaelSims in your codesandbox there seems to be only the basic packages. What I was suggesting is to add the packages you are using so we can have a look and identify the conflict. Have a look at my updated codesandbox I sent initially, in the css I have added some styling for the class `test-chip-class`. Try to add `className="test-chip-class"` in your chip component in case you can override anything else. Also please try to inspect the icon and you should be able to see where the overwriting is coming from. Thanks

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the packages in my sandbox to reflect what I am currently using. The sandbox still works as expected. https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-chip-f3rbi9?file=/src/App.tsx

Re your styles for `test-chip-class`, I cant seem to see those in your sandbox, do you need to save it first? (this is the link i have https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-bhuygs?file=/demo.js)